# Dynamically load image. Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Phaser provides 3 functions: preload, create, update. If the create function renders everything at the first start, then how can it be forced to draw pictures during dynamic loading?

```js
function preload(src = `images/Num_spin/Num_Spin_00359.png.webp`) {
  this.load.image('background', 'images/table_en.png.webp');
  this.load.image('wheel', 'images/UpperWheel.png.webp');
  this.load.image('roulette', src);
}

function create() {
  this.add.image(0, -160, 'background').setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);
  this.add.image(20, 30, 'wheel').setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);
  this.add.image(108, 110, 'roulette').setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7)
}

function update() {
  //Here I call a function that changes url
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create` does not run until the `preload` function has been called and the Loader has finished. If you want to display images as they are loaded, you need to either load them outside of `preload`, or use the various Loader Events to be notified by each file loading.

There are lots of examples showing each method here: http://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=loader/loader%20events/&q=